# Some scraped google results duplicated

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup, google-search

I want to scrape google news result of `panda` in 2016

According to the website, it is around 500 news results in 2016.

I tried to use below code to scrape every results title and URL .

However, many codes consist of many problems .Some result titles are duplicated and it stops at around 120 results . Also , `"&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016";` is not working .It cannot filter the result in 2016 only .

I checked the `string` which is the google search url should be correct in my browser .

I don't know whats wrong with my codes .

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

              String[] line = new String[10000];
          final int[] score = {    0};


            String google = "http://www.google.com.hk/search?q=";

            String search = "panda";

            String charset = "UTF-8";

            String news="&tbm=nws";

      String string = google + URLEncoder.encode(search , charset) + news+"&num=100"+"&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016";
    // 100 results in every pages & results in 2016

      System.out.println(string);
         String userAgent ="Chrome/57.0.2987.133"; 
         int numberOfResultpages = 500; // 

        int idx  =0;
        int count =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResultpages; i++){
   {
           Document document = Jsoup.connect(string).userAgent(userAgent).timeout(5000) .data("start",""+i).get();
        Elements links = document.select( ".r>a");

            for (Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(count++);
                String title = link.text();
                String url = link.absUrl("href"); // Google returns URLs in format "http://www.google.com/url?q=<url>&sa=U&ei=<someKey>".
                url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");

                if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
                    continue; // Ads/news/etc.
                }
                System.out.println("Title: " + title);
                System.out.println("URL: " + url);

                line[idx++]=title; // store every result titles into index[]
           // }

    }
         }
```